# Почему при складывании большого количества чисел, выводится отрицательное число?

Tags: pascal

> Рассматривается множество целых чисел принадлежащих числовому отрезку от 4221 до 17523 которые в восьмеричной СС оканчиваются на 6 и в четверичной на 2. Надо найти сумму таких чисел и минимальное из них.

Написал код на паскале

```
var i, min, sum: integer;
begin
    sum := 0;
    min := 20000;
    for i := 4221 to 17523 do begin
        if(i mod 8 = 6) and (i mod 4 = 2) then 
        begin
            sum := sum + i;
            if i < min then
                min := i;
        end;
    end;
writeln(sum, ' ', min);
end.
```

В итоге на экран в переменной `sum` выводится отрицательное число. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: @Akina 6 наверное :) Ну да, переводить не надо

Comment: @Akina и чего сразу фейспалмить - я уже  не оом возрасте, чтобы все знать и сразу соображать. Сейчас все медленнее, тщательнее :)

Answer (score 1):

Диапазон значений `integer` в Паскале - `-32768..32767`.

А сумма получается `36160272`, поэтому и получается отрицательным.

Используйте тип `longint`.

Comment: Надо уточнять в каком именно паскале. Во всех современных, вроде Pascal.ABC или FreePascal, тип Integer аналогичен типу LongInt. Если не хватает даже его, то можно использовать Cardinal - в нём нет знака, но размер такой же, т.е. он может вместить положительное число в два раза больше, или Int64 (если он есть).

Comment: @Alekcvp, в приложенном коде иных причин не видно, кроме как использования типа с низким диапазоном